# Using environment variable for public desktop path in Windows 10 GPO

Tags: windows, group-policy, windows-server-2016, windows-10

Most of my users' desktop shortcuts are managed by user GPO and they work fine, but I want to use a computer policy to create a shortcut for 'all users' on one machine.

I tried making a computer GPO using both 'Desktop' and 'All Users Desktop' but it doesn't work.

I assume the path to the All Users desktop is `C:\Users\Public\Desktop`, which the GPO editor says can be accessed using the variable `%CommonDesktopDir%`. I tried browsing to %CommonDesktopDir%, but the variable doesn't exist on the endpoint.

I am using Windows Server 2016 with Windows 10 endpoints.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show us screenshots of the shortcut's configuration in the GPO ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oddly enough, some environment variables seem to have been deprecated. Microsoft's documentation for [group policy preference variables](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc753915(v=ws.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) lists common desktop, but it is not present or functional on my Win 10 build 1909 machine. The relevant article is an old one, only "Applies To: Windows 8, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2012."

In lieu of that, you can make use of the `%Public%` variable, which references the path to the Public profile. To get to the all users desktop you would reference `%Public%\Desktop`.

Comment: Thanks - I ended up using C:\Users\Public\Desktop, but a variable is much better. Microsoft are terrible at documenting their own changes.

Comment: Agreed...it seems to be harder to find current documentation for the latest builds of Windows. All of the docs that I found ended with 2008/2012.